# Conflict with @MountPath at Apache Wicket

Tags: java, tomcat, wicket

I'm using Apache Wicket annotations with @MountPath the following page path "/#{id}/#{action}" and in /webapp I have the following structure: 
css/style.css
img/logo.png

When I try access page got an error because Wicket try to resolve style.css and logo.png as the page and not as static file.

I must do a bypass at resource folder /css and /img, how can I do that?

Comment: Are you sure Wicket is the right framework for you if you're trying to manipulate paths at this level? You could try creating your own `IRequestMapper` for this, but the `#{action}` bit just screams "security flaw" to me

Comment: @JeroenSteenbeeke I tried to create a request mapper to solve than, but without success. I solve this problem creating a filter in web.xml and I move the /css and /img files to /commons folder and now the filter do a bypass on requests to /commons/* folder. What do you think about this solution?

Comment: That would be one way of solving it, however that doesn't address why you would want this setup in the first place? Your page is going to be handling every URL with 0-2 segment paths, which means you're using the page as a controller, and a very broad one at that. This is not what pages are for. It could work, but you're probably overcomplicating things by using Wicket for this, so I'm very interested to hear what your use case is and how you intend to use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you face is that you mount a page on the root/index, i.e. "/", with two optional parameters. Wicket will use that page to handle requests to "/", /"one", "/one/two". The static resources you have will be matched because they have two segments, i.e. they will match on both optional parameters.

You can solve/workaround this problem by listing "/css" and "/img" in `ignorePaths` parameter for WicketFilter in web.xml.